# How to remove last element in php

Tags: php

I have to remove the last element in a string. I used `rtrim` in `php` but it is not working.

This is the string:

```
 /search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC
```

I need to remove "&make_order=ASC"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$s = '/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC';
echo substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, '&'));
```

#### Edit:

```
$url = $base_url.trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "&year_order=".$arr['year_order']."" );
//                                            ^
//                                            |_ replace , with .
```

Comment: no its not working it showing empty result

Comment: My example is working. You probably used it in different way. Can you copy/paste how you used it?

Comment: $url = $base_url.trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "&year_order=".$arr['year_order']."" ); tried this.. but not working i am getting /search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipco‌​de=641004&distance=100&make_order=A

Comment: In `trim()` you have `,` insterad of `.`.

Answer (score 1):

trim should work:

```
$string = "/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC";
$string = trim($string, "&make_order=ASC");
```

Comment: $url = $base_url.trim(  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "&year_order=".$arr['year_order'].""  ); tried this.. but not working i am getting /search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=A

Comment: This may happen to work, given the example.. but `trim` keeps on stripping bytes from the first argument that appear in the second argument until it doesn't. `trim` does not strip the string as-is.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that `make_order` will be at the end of the query string - or exist at all. To remove the field properly, you'd have to use something like this:

```
$url = '/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC';

// break down the URL into a path and query string
$parsed = parse_url($url);

// turn the query string into an array that we can manipulate
$qs = array();
parse_str($parsed['query'], $qs);

// remove the unwanted field
unset($qs['make_order']);

// rebuild the URL
$rebuilt = $parsed['path'];
if(!empty($qs)) {
    $rebuilt .= '?' . http_build_query($qs);
}

echo $rebuilt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$actual_link = "/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC";


echo str_replace("&make_order=ASC","",$actual_link);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC";

$args = array_pop(explode($string, "&"));

$string = implode("&", $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways. The easiest might be:

```
$i=strrpos($text,'&');
$newstring=substr($text,0,$i);
```

Comment: i tried this too.. but no use friend

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo trim($str,"&make_order=ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

if `&make_order=ASC` is always going to be at the end, you can use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to do this

```
$str = '/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC';
echo strstr($str,'&make_order=ASC',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove desired key from url.**

Use:

```
$s = '/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100&make_order=ASC';
echo remove_key_from_url($url, 'make_order');
```

Output :

```
/search/listing.html?vehicle_type=&year=&make_name=&model_name=&loc_type=3&zipcode=641004&distance=100
```

Code:

```
function remove_key_from_url($url, $key) {
    if (strpos($url, '?') === false) return $url;
    list($left, $right) = explode('?', $url, 2);
    parse_str($right, $get);
    if (isset($get[$key])) unset($get[$key]);
    return $left . '?' . http_build_query($get);
}
```